# Convert Java Object to String in SpringBoot JPA Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on Springboot MySQL example([Similar example](http://candidjava.com/tutorial/spring-boot-jpa-mysql-example/)). In one of the methods, I want to log JSON data but I am getting,

**com.example.employee.model.Employee@1595ddd2**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employees12/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee getPerson(@PathVariable Long id){
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(id);
    //String str=employee.toString();
    //System.out.println("string is " + str);
    System.out.println(employee); //print json in logs console
    return employee;
}
```

The `return employees;` is giving JSON data. 
I have tried toString(), even that doesnt work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Reimeus: This is not a correct link to duplicate. I think this question should not be closed at all. The OP is definitely aware of how `System.out::println` and `Object::toString` works. He needs to log the outgoing JSON response. Please consider reopening the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter` from `ObjectMapper`. This enables pretty print.

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@RequestMapping(value="/employees12/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee getPerson(@PathVariable Long id){
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(id);
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(employee));
    return employee;
}
```

If you want the output just in compact mode, use `writeValueAsString`

```
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working as expected. I am a non-Java guy and was searching for a solution for the last couple of hours. I did not know about this ObjectMapper PrettyPrinter concept.

Answer (score 1):

In the getPerson() method, use `objectMapper.writeValueAsString()` to get the JSON of the employee object:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employees12/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee getPerson(@PathVariable Long id){
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(id);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
    return employee;
}
```

Adding a `toString()` in Employee class, with the `ObjectMapper` from Jackson to serialize the Employee instance. The advantage of overriding the `toString()` method in the Employee class is you can just do `System.out.println(employee);` anywhere to get the JSON representation of the Employee object.

```
 public String toString(){
     String serialized ="";
        try{
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            serialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        }catch(JsonProcessingException jpe){
            jpe.printStackTrace();
        }
    return serialized;
 }
```

Comment: It returns Object parsed to string with `{`, `/` `}` chars e.g,: `"{\"street\":\"scEEqbJsKXIhmdXzzjeXxvLlWSMCdz\",\"buildingNumber\":\"cDlmnRjhBJDyZcDgnb\",\"city\":\"f"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use google gson library:

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(this);
}
```

Comment: or reflection using apache lang